# How should I test for multivariate GARCH effects for residuals of a model?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, garch

I would like to test the multivariate GARCH effect of a multivariate time series. The multivariate Ljung-Box test can do this. However I am also looking for a test to show that a DCC or CCC model can capture the effect of cross-correlations. As the model gives the correlation matrix but does not eliminate the cross correlations, the residuals still cannot pass the multivariate Ljung-Box test. Is there a good way to show that the model already capture the effect of cross-correlations?

Thanks.